# Googleapi searching drive by title always returns 0 items

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using google api dot net client, and i'm a bit confused.

Following code returns me the entire list of a specific folder (with an Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX).

```
List<File> result = new List<File>();
FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
request.Q = "'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' in parents";
request.MaxResults = 35;
FileList files = request.Fetch();
```

As example one item of this FileList is

```
"id": "0B5XhOfl0NZ2cZ1M1aVBPcVlTUTA",
"title": "87BC1CAE-A01C-43A1-BB21-BE3DA6D6C7DC"
```

If i change the query, searching for a title, i receive always an empty FileList.

```
List<File> result = new List<File>();
FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
request.Q = "title = '87BC1CAE-A01C-43A1-BB21-BE3DA6D6C7DC'";
request.MaxResults = 35;
FileList files = request.Fetch();
```

It does'nt matter, if the operator is '=' or 'contains', or by searching only a part of the directory name:

```
title contains '87BC1CAE'
```

I receive correct results only by searching for IDs.
Following code works flawless:

```
File file = service.Files.Get(fileId).Fetch();

Console.WriteLine("Title: " + file.Title);
Console.WriteLine("Description: " + file.Description);
Console.WriteLine("MIME type: " + file.MimeType);
```

Help please :)

@AliAfshar
Raw HTTP responses:
1st case (title = '87BC1CAE-A01C-43A1-BB21-BE3DA6D6C7DC')

```
request.Fetch()
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : DotNetOpenAuth, Version=4.0.0.11165, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246 (official)
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Preparing to send AssertionFlowMessage (2.0) message.
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Sending AssertionFlowMessage request.
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : HTTP POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : The following required parameters were missing from the DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Messages.AccessTokenFailedResponse message: {error,}
   TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Received UnauthorizedResponse response.
   {Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.FileList}
_etag: "\"Q0cVodxX8sh4vfxZTlOyWcmmc0k/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8\""
_items: Count = 0
_kind: null
_nextLink: null
_nextPageToken: null
_selfLink: null
ETag: "\"Q0cVodxX8sh4vfxZTlOyWcmmc0k/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8\""
Items: Count = 0
Kind: null
NextLink: null
NextPageToken: null
SelfLink: null
```

2nd case ('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' in parents )

```
request.Fetch()
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : DotNetOpenAuth, Version=4.0.0.11165, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246 (official)
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Preparing to send AssertionFlowMessage (2.0) message.
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Sending AssertionFlowMessage request.
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : HTTP POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : The following required parameters were missing from the  DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Messages.AccessTokenFailedResponse message: {error,}
TestGoogleApi.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Received UnauthorizedResponse response.
{Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.FileList}
_etag: "\"Q0cVodxX8sh4vfxZTlOyWcmmc0k/Jyx7utsp71-_JwU5RHnI_VZmL5o\""
_items: Count = 1575
_kind: null
_nextLink: null
_nextPageToken: null
_selfLink: null
ETag: "\"Q0cVodxX8sh4vfxZTlOyWcmmc0k/Jyx7utsp71-_JwU5RHnI_VZmL5o\""
Items: Count = 1575
Kind: null
NextLink: null
NextPageToken: null
SelfLink: null
```

---

**Updated on 2013 Feb 02**
Ok excuse me for delay.
i used fiddler and here is captured result:

---

first request:

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: DotNetOpenAuth/4.0.0.11165
Host: accounts.google.com
Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 603
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=assertion&assertion_type=http%3A%2F%2Foauth.net%2Fgrant_type%2Fjwt%2F1.0%2Fbearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI0MjYwNjE5OTE1NzktYXEzMHBhcmVsYmpsb3BrMjlqcXFvdjhsdWhic2o3YjdAZGV2ZWxvcGVyLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvZHJpdmUiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vby9vYXV0aDIvdG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjEzNjAwNjA0NDMsImlhdCI6MTM2MDA1Njg0M30.dk7Vdu-................-LIw0sFrVko-VWL7-elhz59VQcU_.........
```

first answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 09:34:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Content-Length: 128

{
  "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZS-...........-a8HRHfMZ-NxXekx",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}
```

second request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json&fields=items(id%2Ctitle)%2CnextPageToken&prettyPrint=true&maxResults=2000&q=title%20%3D%20'87BC1CAE-A01C-43A1-BB21-BE3DA6D6C7DC' HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6ZS-...........-a8HRHfMZ-NxXekx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: TestGoogleApi google-api-dotnet-client/ Win32NT/6.1.7600.0 (gzip)
Host: www.googleapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

second answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 09:34:04 GMT
Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 09:34:04 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
ETag: "Q0cVodxX8sh4vfxZTlOyWcmmc0k/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 17
Server: GSE

{
 "items": []
}
```

---

as you see items count is 0.

If i make the same request via web interface
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list it gives me 2 items, as it should be.

This is made with https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

```
GET /drive/v2/files?alt=json&fields=items(id%2Ctitle)%2CnextPageToken&prettyPrint=true&maxResults=2000&q=title%20%3D%20'87BC1CAE-A01C-43A1-BB21-BE3DA6D6C7DC' HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: OAuth ya29.AHES6ZSDr7bDFMQxjR........ObzyEhkzQmN

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 220
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
Content-location: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json&fields=items(id%2Ctitle)%2CnextPageToken&prettyPrint=true&maxResults=2000&q=title%20%3D%20'87BC1CAE-A01C-43A1-BB21-BE3DA6D6C7DC'
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Etag: "Q0cVodxX8sh4vfxZTlOyWcmmc0k/oUg90Ml6_g3EsaXCogiJOEMkZ-M"
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
-content-encoding: gzip
Server: GSE
Reason: OK
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 15:30:09 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 15:30:09 GMT
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "0B5XhOf....VlTUTA",
   "title": "87BC1CAE-A01C-43A1-BB21-BE3DA6D6C7DC"
  },
  {
   "id": "0B5XhO....EbGRLVVVReGM",
   "title": "87BC1CAE-A01C-43A1-BB21-BE3DA6D6C7DC"
  }
 ]
}
```

Thank you very much, i really appreciate your help

Comment: That certainly looks like a bug the way you have described it. I'll investigate.

Comment: Can you get some raw http data, so I can check the client isn't doing something crazy please?

Comment: @AliAfshar - i just added some raw http data in my question. thank you.

Comment: @MarcoCollini please use Fiddler to capture the HTTP requests, the data you attached doesn't really tell what request was sent to the API. Have you also tried sending the same request with the OAuth 2.0 Playground? https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino - below you'll find some data more... ciao e grazie!

Comment: Both your requests are to the same URL. Which scope are you using? Are both requests from the same user?

Comment: @AliAfshar The scope is  DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue(), aka https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.  In my project i'm currently using a service account as described here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the confusion is due to the fact that you are using a service account in your code, but comparing the results with what you see in the web interface.

When using the web interface or the OAuth Playground, you are authorizing the app to use your personal account and not a service account. The service account doesn't have access to the same files you have access to, as it is actually an application-owned account.

If you want to use a service account to access your files, you should perform domain-wide delegation as explained at https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

This still doesn't explain why some queries return results and others don't, but please try everything again without using service accounts and update the issue if things still don't work as expected.